# How to show origin image size in qml Image component?

Tags: qml

I tried to show origin image size in QML Image component,code like:

```js
    Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    Rectangle {
        id: imageRect
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height
        anchors.fill: parent
        DragHandler {
             acceptedButtons: Qt.RightButton
             target: sourceImage
             xAxis.enabled: true
             yAxis.enabled: true

        }
        Image {
            id: sourceImage
            source: "qrc:/2.jpg"
            width: sourceSize.width
            height: sourceSize.height
            MouseArea {
                width:parent.width
                height:parent.height
                onClicked: {
                    print(mouse.x, mouse.y)
                    print(sourceImage.x, sourceImage.y)
                }

            }
        }
    }

}
```

but the image is not fit with the parent's size, how can i fit the image to its parent and keep image origin size?

Comment: Please check the [Qt docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-image.html): _If the width and height properties are not specified, the Image automatically uses the size of the loaded image_. It's unclear what `sourceSize` is but anyway, you just need to avoid setting the image size.

Comment: _fit the image to its parent and keep image origin size_ ... don't you think these are probably mutually exclusive things?

Answer (score 0):

By default, the `Image` component will automatically set `width` and `height` to source image contents. You use this if you don't want any scaling to occur.

In the following example, I render the original `Image`, the Hubble view of the Pillars of Creation. I put it inside a `Flickable` with `ScrollBars` so that you can pan the image.

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Page {
    property string mouseInfo
    Flickable {
        id: flickable
        anchors.fill: parent
        contentWidth: image.width + 20
        contentHeight: image.height + 20
        clip: true
        ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar {
            width: 20
            policy: ScrollBar.AlwaysOn
        }
        ScrollBar.horizontal: ScrollBar {
            height: 20
            policy: ScrollBar.AlwaysOn
        }
    
        Image {
            id: image
            source: "https://www.arcgis.com/sharing/rest/content/items/d0ecaa3fd9ef45c8ad255989ef6ded07/data"
            MouseArea {
                anchors.fill: parent
                onClicked: mouseInfo = `${mouseX},${mouseY}`;
            }
        }
    }
    footer: Frame {
        Text {
           text: "image: %1x%2 mouseInfo:%3".arg(image.width).arg(image.height).arg(mouseInfo)
        }
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=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)